# Swift CoreData Save Attribute with Type of Custom Class

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm new to using CoreData as the database to store the users' data in order to support offline app usage. I have set up the data model for my objects and some of the attributes have to be stored in the type of my other object classes. However, it seems to be saved successfully but it returns `nil` when I tried to fetch the results from the database. I also looked into the SQLite database file to see what happened to the field that stored into CoreData giving me `nil` as the results (and the returning type is found to be `Optional(Any)`), and found that the attribute of the data was stored in the type of `BLOB`.

The results stored in SQLite:

[image: SQLite Database]

Originally, my app can only be used when network is available but I'm trying to turn it be supporting offline access. However, I have be sticking with the issues and do not know how to solve it, and even I'm not sure whether I was doing in the right way.

One of the example of my custom object classes `StudentMarkList`:

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData

@objc(StudentMarkList)

class StudentMarkList: NSObject {
    var id = Int() // Student ID in DB (Primary Key)
    var paperId = String() // Paper ID which the student attended
    var studentClass = String() // Student class
    var totalMark = Int() // Total mark of the attended paper
    var allMarked = Bool() // Flag whether student's paper is all marked
    var markList = [MarkList]() // Array of marks for each question <- Custom object class of defining the structure of each question's mark

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    init(id:Int, paperId:String, studentClass:String, totalMark:Int, allMarked:Bool, markList:[MarkList]){
        self.id = id
        self.paperId = paperId
        self.studentClass = studentClass
        self.totalMark = totalMark
        self.allMarked = allMarked
        self.markList = markList
    }

    func save() {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }

        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        managedContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "StudentMarkList", in: managedContext)!
        let studentMarkList = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)

        studentMarkList.setValue(self.id, forKey: "id")
        studentMarkList.setValue(self.paperId, forKey: "paperId")
        studentMarkList.setValue(self.studentClass, forKey: "studentClass")
        studentMarkList.setValue(self.totalMark, forKey: "totalMark")
        studentMarkList.setValue(self.allMarked, forKey: "allMarked")
        studentMarkList.setValue(self.markList, forKey: "markList")

        if managedContext.hasChanges {
            do {
                try managedContext.save()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Model of `StudentMarkList`:

[image: StudentMarkList model]

The corresponding custom object class `MarkList`:

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData

@objc(MarkList)

class MarkList: NSObject, NSCoding {
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(questionId, forKey: "questionId")
        aCoder.encode(questionNo, forKey: "questionNo")
        aCoder.encode(questionMark, forKey: "questionMark")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        guard let questionId = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "questionId") as? Int,
            let questionNo = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "questionNo") as? Int,
            let questionMark = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "questionMark") as? String else {
                return nil
        }
        self.questionId = questionId
        self.questionNo = questionNo
        self.questionMark = questionMark
    }

    var questionId = Int()
    var questionNo = Int()
    var questionMark = String()

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    init(questionId: Int, questionNo: Int, questionMark: String) {
        self.questionId = questionId
        self.questionNo = questionNo
        self.questionMark = questionMark
    }

    func save() {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }

        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        managedContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "MarkList", in: managedContext)!
        let markList = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)

        markList.setValue(self.questionId, forKey: "questionId")
        markList.setValue(self.questionNo, forKey: "questionNo")
        markList.setValue(self.questionMark, forKey: "questionMark")

        if managedContext.hasChanges {
            do {
                try managedContext.save()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Model of `MarkList`:

[image: MarkList model]

The function `save()` is used to save the instance to CoreData as the corresponding object class.

Hope someone can help me or clarify me the concepts of using CoreData. Thank you!

Comment: Kelvin, could you please update your question to confirm the data type for `MarkList` (assume it is Transformable) and if practical to do so, a screenshot of the model editor `StudentMarkList`?

Comment: @andrewbuilder Sure, I have added the information of the entities. The type of `MarkList` referred in `StudentMarkList` is Transformable. Sorry for updating late...

Answer (score 0):

To achieve custom class as attribute of your CoreData entity. Each class should be treated as separate entity and data linking should be manage through relationships

You have to create new entity for marklist, StudentMarkList will be your parent entity.

[image]

Simply add relation of marklist to studentMarkList, Select your StudentMarkList entity and create relation as shown in image. Don't worry about inverse follow next step it will be clear.

[image]

Now select Marklist entity and add relationship like shown below

[image]

Please make sure to change class codegen to use manual

[image]

Comment: Please use better names for the relationships, the normal way is to name them the same as the entity the relationship points to but starting with a lowercase and with an s at the end if it is a to-many relationship. So markLists and studentMarkList

Comment: @Abhi Yaduwanshi Thanks for your answer. I tried to add the relationships but it seems to be the same that the data of `MarkList` attribute in `StudentMarkList` was still stored as previously shown.

Comment: @Abhi Yaduwanshi I have tried and it always returns `nil` for `markList` in `StudentMarkList` when fetching the results from CoreData...

Comment: after building relation you have to create new NSObjectmanaged for both of your class.

     

                    let arrMarksOrderedSet = NSOrderedSet(array: arrMarkList)
                    StudentMarkList.addToMarks_rel(arrMarksOrderedSet)

And while saving the data into relation use this approach

Comment: @AbhiYaduwanshi Do you mean by creating subclasses and the core data properties of NSObjectManaged?

Comment: Yes, Simply select your xcdatamodel -> Click on editor -> create NSManagedObject subclass , and make changes to your save method

Comment: @AbhiYaduwanshi But the object class definition will be duplicated to my original class declaration. Sorry that I do not quite understand how to "migrate" my existing object declaration to the core data design...

Comment: You have to create separate class for CoreData modal (e.g StudentMarkListCoreData) and a functions (Save and fetch ) need to kept in CoreData class whose responsible to convert your CoreData values into Your desired modal (StudentMarkList) and vice versa

Comment: @AbhiYaduwanshi So that means I just simply convert the original class to CoreData model? Because somebody said I should not use the original class and create the saving function (like what I did in the code). Instead, I was told to follow the docs and use the save and fetch functions, and it will keep in memory and save to the CoreData DB. Is that right?

Comment: Yes which means you have a class for CoreData model and one your original model class.

Comment: @AbhiYaduwanshi I tried to create the core data classes via "Create NSManagedObject subclass" and I found that there is a variable created for the relationship attribute set up in the core data model: `@NSManaged public var <relationship_attr>: MyObjectClass?`. How to handle it?

Comment: While you fetch data from database use this : 

`if let marksDetail = self.marks_rel{
 // do your handling here
}`



Use this while you save: `studentdMarkListCD.addToMarks_rel(markList)`